# Send Data Between ViewModels | MVVM | .net Maui

Tags: .net, mobile, mvvm, maui

I'm building an app using .net Maui (the app is for android and windows) and i'dont have experience in mobile Development

I wanna know how i can pass data (objects) between 2 ViewModels.

Actually i' using MessagingCenter to send data from the *ViewModel A* and suscribe in the *ViewModel B*, but i'dont know is this is the best way to do it .

In the first versions i send the data in the constructor of the ViewModel Class using a parameter defined in the views, but i generate a dependency between the views and the viewmodels

Comment: `MessagingCenter` has been deprecated in favor of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger

Comment: Do you need to pass data during navigation? Is so you can use the techniques described at [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Can you be more specific and show what you're trying to do? What do the ViewModels look like and what data do you want to pass and when?

Comment: This might be help [Pass Data Between ViewModels in FreshMvvm for Xamarin.Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBtNX0AylKc)

Comment: Messaging I do when I do not care "if" and "how many" other parts are listening, and I do not  want any connections between those parts whatsoever. Obviously passing data from A to B during navigation is not one of them. So if this is your case...

Answer (score 0):

Using Shell Navigation you can pass and receive primitive/object data between ViewModels. I leave you a small example:

Step 1 in first ViewModel (passing data):

```
public void GoToPage2() {

    var navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Yourkey", YourObject },
    };

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Page2),false,navigationParameters);
}
```

Step 2 in second ViewModel (receiving data):

```
public class Page2ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged,IQueryAttributable {

  public YourObjectType YourObject { get; private set; }
    
  public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        YourObject = query["YourKey"] as YourObjectType;
        OnPropertyChanged("YourObject");
    }
    
}
```

Important: Use IQueryAttributable in your class.

Here the documentation what helped me. [.NET MAUI Shell Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0)